# Programming a Nucleo 32 board using ST-LINK

Tags: microcontroller, programming, st-link

I'm using [this](https://os.mbed.com/platforms/ST-Nucleo-F303K8/) Nucleo board but unfortunately after I programmed it I have attached it to a base PCB in such a way that I can't access its USB port anymore. If I want to make an update and access its USB port I have to de-solder the entire board.

I have access to an [ST-LINK-V3](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stlink-v3set.html) but I have never used it.

Is it possible to program the Nucleo 32 by using the ST-LINK and its pins (not the USB port)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can program the NUCLEO-F303K8 board without using the USB port by using the STLINK programmer and its pins. The STLINK is a built-in tool that helps you program and debug the microcontroller on the board. You can connect the STLINK programmer to the SWDIO, SWCLK, NRST, and GND pins on the board, and then use programming software to communicate with the STLINK and program the microcontroller.

Comment: Please see my question here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/669898/unable-to-program-nucleo-32-board-via-an-external-st-link-programmer I couldnt make it work